# LocalDate changes when being persisted to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Java application which runs on a Linux machine and which retrieves some data from an API and saves it into a MySQL database.
When I am trying to save date and time(LocalDate, LocalTime) into the database, the values from Java and database are different.

For example, for the date 9 October 2021 and time 00:00 London time, I see in the database the right date, the 9th of October, but the time is 23:00 instead of 00:00. I have to mention that it worked before the hour change from DST to GMT.
My Java code for saving into the database is this and when debugging on it, the values remain right, the 9th of October for the date and 00:00 for the time:

```
ZonedDateTime utcTime = fixturesList.get(i).getEvent_date();
ZoneId london = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
ZonedDateTime dateTimeLondon = utcTime.toInstant().atZone(london);
currentMatchEntity.setDate(dateTimeLondon.toLocalDate());
currentMatchEntity.setTime(dateTimeLondon.toLocalTime());
matchesRepository.save(currentMatchEntity);
```

I thought that MySql might have the wrong timezone, so I ran the below query, but the result seems to be right:
[image]

Also, I thought that there might be some issues with the Linux machine, so I ran the below command, but the outcome seems also right.

[image]

Hibernate properties from Java:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://databaseAddress/databaseName;serverTimezone=GMT</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Why does MySQL save the time as "23:00" instead of "00:00"? Why does it decrease the hour with one? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is due to the way you are updating the MySQL database from Java (using JDBC, right?) Can you [edit] your question and post that code?

Comment: yes, it is through jdbc and I have the common properties there

Comment: I also added the hibernate.cfg properties

Answer (score 0):

Nov 10. May be DayLightSaving issue.

Comment: I also thought about this, but how can it be fixed?

Comment: But it is okay depending on Time Zone.  If ZonedDateTime is not mandatory, replace it with LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be able to avoid writing code to convert timezones.  But it requires

- Having clients and servers -- both OS and MySQL -- set correctly, and
- Correctly picking between `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`.

`DATETIME` is like taking a picture of the clock on the wall.  It has the timezone and daylight/standard time already set.

`TIMESTAMP` is stored in UTC.  What you enter is quietly converted to UTC based on a few settings.  When reading, it is converted back.

Another person fetching a `TIMESTAMP` from your your server through his computer will see a different time than what you stored.  For `DATETIME`, you both see the same string.

To see how your MySQL server is configured:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';
```

If it says `"SYSTEM"`, then look in the OS settings for what that means.

Caution: Britain has used DST *some* years.